# inter changin the limit and integral in a specific function

Tags: real-analysis

I'm stuck in a real analysis problem. The essence of my question is about interchanging the limit and the integral for a specific function. I know something about the "uniform convergnece" but I realy don't know how to figure it out in my problem.
My question is as follows:

What are the necessary and sufficent conditions (I'm ok  even with only the sufficent condition) on $g(x)$, such that we can interchange the following limit and  integral:

$$\lim_{a \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{g\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)-1}\left(e^{-\frac{1}{a}}-1 -\left(e^{-\frac{1}{a g\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)}}-1\right) g\left(\frac{x}{a}\right) \right)e^{-\frac{x}{a}} \, dx $$

thank you so much...

Comment: Look at uniform convergence, not uniform continuity.

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake... @AndrewSalmon